# Insert data from a subset table to a superset table in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

I have a superset set table like so:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
```

I also have subset table whose  columns will get created dynamically and I dont know the column names beforehand ,but the column names will always be subset of  columns that are present in super set table :

For eg .
subset table might be :

```
**CASE1**:

col1 col2
1     2
```

Or in some case it might be

```
**CASE2**:

col1 col5 col6
1     5    6
```

Or it might be :

```
**CASE3**:

col3 col6 
3    6
```

I want to insert data in superset table only for those columns that are present in subset .For the columns that are not present in subset ,I want to put some default value :

Case1 :
superset table should have :

```
 col1 col2  col3            col4            col5            col6
 1    2     defualt_value   defualt_value   defualt_value   defualt_value
```

Case2 :
superset table should have :

```
 col1   col2            col3            col4            col5    col6
 1      defualt_value   defualt_value   defualt_value   5       6
```

Case3 :
superset table should have :

```
col1           col2            col3   col4            col5               col6
defualt_value  defualt_value   3      defualt_value   defualt_value       6
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help ...

Test table and data (from your question: "... insert data in superset table only for those columns that are present in subset .For the columns that are not present in subset ,I want to put some default value ")

```
create table superset (
  id   number generated always as identity start with 7000 primary key
, col1 number default 111
, col2 number default 222
, col3 number default 333
, col4 number default 444
, col5 number default 555
, col6 number default 666
, remarks varchar2( 256 ) default 'subset id unknown'
);

-- insert test data
begin
-- case 1
  insert into superset ( col1, col2, remarks ) values ( 1, 2, '**CASE1**' ) ;
-- case 2
  insert into superset ( col1, col5, col6, remarks ) values ( 1, 5, 6, '**CASE2**' ) ;  
-- case 3
  insert into superset ( col3, col6, remarks ) values ( 3, 6 , '**CASE3**') ;
--4 some other stuff - the inserted rows do not belong to any known subset
  insert into superset ( col1 ) values ( 1 );
  insert into superset ( col2 ) values ( 2 );
  insert into superset ( col3 ) values ( 3 );
  insert into superset ( col4 ) values ( 4 );
  insert into superset ( col5 ) values ( 5 );
  insert into superset ( col6 ) values ( 6 );
end;
/
```

The SUPERSET table now contains:

```
SQL> select * from superset;
ID    COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5  COL6  REMARKS            
7000  1     2     333   444   555   666   **CASE1**          
7001  1     222   333   444   5     6     **CASE2**          
7002  111   222   3     444   555   6     **CASE3**          
7003  1     222   333   444   555   666   subset id unknown  
7004  111   2     333   444   555   666   subset id unknown  
7005  111   222   3     444   555   666   subset id unknown  
7006  111   222   333   4     555   666   subset id unknown  
7007  111   222   333   444   5     666   subset id unknown  
7008  111   222   333   444   555   6     subset id unknown
```

Now, you can create a view for each subset eg

```
create or replace view subset1_view
as 
select col1, col2 
from superset
where remarks = '**CASE1**' ;

SQL> select * from subset1_view;
COL1  COL2  
1     2
```

Or

```
create or replace view subset1_view
as 
select * 
from superset
where remarks = '**CASE1**' ;

SQL> select * from subset1_view;
ID    COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5  COL6  REMARKS    
7000  1     2     333   444   555   666   **CASE1**
```